# Python: apply if else to multiple variables within a grouping to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have some data that looks like this:

```
d = {'id' : ["A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B"],
'month' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2],
'week' : [1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4]}
example_df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

I want to group by `id` and create a new column based on the contents of `month` and `week` but I get this error: `KeyError: 'month'`. Here is my attempt:

```
example_df['final_score'] = (
example_df.groupby(['id'])
.transform(lambda x: 'converted' if ((x['month'] == 1) &
                                     (x['week'].isin([3,4].any())))
           else 'not_converted')
                                 )
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: what is your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

`groupby.transform` handles only **one** column at a time.

Use [`groupby.transform('any')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to build a mask to use with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m1 = example_df['month'].eq(1)
m2 = example_df['week'].isin([3,4]).groupby(example_df['id']).transform('any')

example_df['final_score'] = np.where(m1&m2, 'converted', 'not_converted')
```

output:

```
   id  month  week    final_score
0   A      1     1      converted
1   A      1     2      converted
2   A      1     3      converted
3   A      1     4      converted
4   A      2     1  not_converted
5   A      2     2  not_converted
6   B      1     1      converted
7   B      1     2      converted
8   B      2     1  not_converted
9   B      2     2  not_converted
10  B      2     3  not_converted
11  B      2     4  not_converted
```

Answer (score 0):

What result do you want? Is it maybe one you can get with this line of code ?

```
import numpy as np
example_df['final_score'] = np.where((example_df['month'] == 1 & example_df['week'].isin([3,4])), "converted",  "not converted")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need a `groupby` and `transform` for this given that your `transform` is not dependent on the grouping -

A simple `apply` like this should work -

```py
example_df['final_score'] = example_df.apply(lambda x: 'converted' if ((x['month'] == 1) &
                                     (x['week'] in [3, 4]))
           else 'not_converted', axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   id  month  week    final_score
0   A      1     1  not_converted
1   A      1     2  not_converted
2   A      1     3      converted
3   A      1     4      converted
4   A      2     1  not_converted
5   A      2     2  not_converted
6   B      1     1  not_converted
7   B      1     2  not_converted
8   B      2     1  not_converted
9   B      2     2  not_converted
10  B      2     3  not_converted
11  B      2     4  not_converted
```

Comment: I imagine that a single matching week in the group should expand to all group members?